# Adding a horizontal Adapter in a vertical one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I need to "add" a horizontal adapter to a vertical one using CocatAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came out:

lets say you have an adapter (vertical orientation) wich is composed by several others adapters (

some of them, with horizontal orientation ). If that the case, you can use a great combination between Concat Adapter and my class.

### The class is ->

```
class HorizontalListAdapter<T>(
    private val adapter: ListAdapter<T, *>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalListAdapter.ViewHolder<T>>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int,
    ): ViewHolder<T> = ViewHolder(
        parent.inflate(
            R.layout.horizontal_generic_recycler_layout),
            adapter
    )

    class ViewHolder<T>(view: View, private val adapter: ListAdapter<T, *>) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bind() {
            itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_horizontal_generic).adapter = adapter
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = R.layout.horizontal_generic_recycler_layout

    fun submitList(list: List<T>) {
        val currentAdapterListItems = adapter.currentList
        if (list != currentAdapterListItems) {
            adapter.submitList(list)
            notifyItemChanged(0)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder<T>, position: Int) {
        holder.bind()
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 1
}
```

### "generic" xml is ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_horizontal_generic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Last, but not least, your Adapter for the `horizontal recycler ->`

```
class Adapter(private val callback: Callback) :
    ListAdapter<ItemProductPresentation, ViewHolder>(ProductPresentationDiffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(
            ListItemProductPresentationBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            ),
            callback
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ListItemProductPresentationBinding,
        private val callback: Callback,
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(input: ItemProductPresentation) {
            binding.imgChecked.isVisible = input.selected
        }
    }

    interface Callback { fun onPresentationSelected(presentationItem: ItemProductPresentation) }
}

object ProductPresentationDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ItemProductPresentation>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: ItemProductPresentation,
            newItem: ItemProductPresentation
    ): Boolean = oldItem.presentation == newItem.presentation

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: ItemProductPresentation,
            newItem: ItemProductPresentation
    ): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
}
```

### So, in your View ->

```
    private val adapter = ConcatAdapter()
    ....
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        horizontalAdapter = HorizontalListAdapter(ProductPresentationAdapter(this))
        adapter.addAdapter(horizontalAdapter)
        binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
    }
```

### View´s xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bkg_white_ffffff_rounded_12">

           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

So, this way, the HorizontalListAdapter class basically adapts a ListAdapter ( you can make this class allow also another kind of Adapters ) that is supposed to be in a horizontal adapter inside a bigger adapter that scroll vertically. In this example, I passed a callback and, it works just fine in the view.

**Hope this helps.**

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how horizontal recycler view could work (in horizontal direction) as an item of the vertical one that has ConcatAdapter. According to this answer it is not possible (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66947576/5694410).